# Extracting a text in regex

Tags: java, regex

I have text in csv format like below.

```
hi="hello",how="are",,,you="",thank="you"
```

Please help me to get a regex to extract the above text

```
hello,are,,,,you
```

Basically I want to take only values in the above key value pairs and keep the commas as they are (technically to frame a perfect csv)

Note: I am actually looking for a pure regex, not with java functions..please.

Thank you

Comment: Where is the pattern i your text?

Comment: Sorry, but why are you looking for a "pure regex"?  If you have some condition that _requires_ the use of one regex, please explain what that condition is.  Most posters who ask questions like this don't really have a good reason for wanting a regex--they think regexes are some magical beast that can solve any problem.  In many cases, using java functions are the best approach.  So you will need a good explanation why you don't want java functions.

Comment: Try `text.replaceAll("\\w+=\"(.*?)\"", "$1")`.

Answer (score 1):

So starting from your sentence :

```
String str = "hi=\"hello\",how=\"are\",,,you=\"\",thank=\"you\"";
```

You can remove all occurences of `word="` and of `"` :

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\w*=\"|\")", "");  //remove word=" OR "
```

Another way, this will catch the group `key="value"` and replace it by `value` :

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\w+=\"(.*?)\"", "$1");  // $1 is the value catch in ()
```